window.print() sometimes won't work on mobile browsers (chome, edge, brave , ect)
I am working on the cloud POS system when using the window. print() works most of the time. but, after 10–20 prints, the Android print dialogue won't come. The print won't come while using my app on Chrome, and if you open Edge and try to print it, it will work. Also, restarting the phone will work.
I tried to change many settings on my print service, but still it failed. I need a solution to print so many invoices without an issue.

Is there any way you can reproduce this in an emulator or through the mobile layout in the Chrome debugger on a PC? Or do you know if any errors are being logged to the console? See if this helps you get started: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging
